# How to define an offset in CardDav REPORT request

Tags: carddav

I am using cardDav standard and I have to handle a lot of contact.

The carddav standard does define a way to limit the number of results ([doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-8.6.1)) with REPORT request but is there any way to define an offset? I would like to retrieve all my contacts by batch.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [WebDAV Sync](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578).

That said, not all server implementation do not support the paging mechanism defined by this specification.